# Handler redefinition with more arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, events

Trying to make ball animation on windows forms. The main problem how to store ball's parameters and paint it.

First of all, set timer which each tick will invoke paint event. But for this it's necessary to pass ball's arguments to handler.

So:

```
private void Animation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Balls ball = new Balls();

        Timer tmr1 = new Timer();
        tmr1.Tick += (sender, e) => moveBall(sender, e, ball);

        tmr1.Interval = 200;
        tmr1.Start();
}
```

But I have problem CS0136 because of redeclaration *sender* and *e*.

Also, the same problem in new handler:

```
public void moveBall(object sender, EventArgs e, Balls ball)
{
            ...

            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler((sender, e) => onPaint(sender, e, ball)); 
}
```

My paint handler looks like this:

```
private void onPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, Balls ball)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, ball.BallX, ball.BallY,
    ball.BallWidth, ball.BallHeight);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, ball.BallX, ball.BallY,
    ball.BallWidth, ball.BallHeight);
}
```

I know, it's possible to store coordinates and velocity of ball as static and then just use *Refresh()*, but it's have to use class.

Comment: The `tick` event signature only accepts the `sender` and `event args`, you can't change that.

Comment: @Codexer, know. But how to redeclare it? More precisely, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Write `tmr1.Tick += (s2, e2) => moveBall(s2, e2, ball);` and same for .Paint

Comment: @Codexer Lambda is my own function - I can name its arguments as I wish

Comment: @Codexer I don't get your concern... `Tick` has a handler with two arguments - one is `object` another is `EventArgs`, I named them `s2` and `e2` and pass them to `moveBall` function - why should I care for `sender` and `e` at all. We can even change `AnimationLoad` handler to be `private void Animation_Load(object _0, EventArgs _1)` and it will still work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Custom event arguments to timer\_TICK event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841359/passing-custom-event-arguments-to-timer-tick-event)

Comment: thx, @Quercus, there are no errors now. But the programm doesn't work, but I'll fix it.

Comment: thx, @Codexe, don't know that's it's possible struct for tag. Maybe it's better to write like this.